# How to Distinguish Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese on Android?

Tags: android, locale, chinese-locale

I'm using Locale to get the language code of my android device (Nexus S)

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()
```

Everything is fine except I get "zh" which means Chinese. I expected to get "zh_cn" and "zh_tw", then I can distinguish beteen simplified and traditional Chinese.

Is there any other way to distinguish which Chinese is using on Android Device?

P.S. I'm using Unity3D, my goal is making a plugin help Unity3D to get the android language setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me when I want to get the current locale of device.

```
Locale.getDefault().toString()
```

It returns name of the current locale. Like "zh_TW" or "zh_CN".